# Konva - visualize custom hit area

Tags: konvajs

Is there an easy way to visualize a custom hit area shape?

As described here
https://konvajs.github.io/docs/events/Custom_Hit_Region.html
the hitFunc attribute can be set to a function that uses the supplied context to draw a custom hit area / region. Something like this:

```
var star = new Konva.Star({
  ...
  hitFunc: function (context) {
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(0, 0, this.getOuterRadius() + 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
    context.closePath()
    context.fillStrokeShape(this)
  }
})
```

For debugging purposes, I would like an easy way to toggle visual rendering of the shape (circle in this case), eg by filling it yellow.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no public API for that. But you still can add hit canvas into the page somewhere and see how it looks:

```
const hitCanvas = layer.hitCanvas._canvas;
document.body.appendChild(hitCanvas);
// disable absolute position:
hitCanvas.style.position = '';
```

http://jsbin.com/mofocagupi/1/edit?js,output

Or you can add hit canvas on top of the stage and apply an opacity to make scene canvases visible:

```
const hitCanvas = layer.hitCanvas._canvas;
stage.getContainer().appendChild(hitCanvas);
hitCanvas.style.opacity = 0.5;
hitCanvas.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

http://jsbin.com/gelayolila/1/edit?js,output